# Linear transformation that permutes and translates

Tags: linear-transformations

Can you determine the $3 \times 3$ standard matrix of a linear transformation that permutes and translates the components of a $3$-dimensional vector as

$V=(V_x,V_y,V_z)$

$T(V)=(V_z + 1,V_y + 1,V_x + 1$)?

Comment: I'm not sure this was edited correctly.  I think the "+1"s aren't supposed to be in the subscripts.  Is the question supposed to state that $T(V) = (V_z + 1, V_y + 1, V_x + 1)$?

Comment: Either way, the question doesn't make sense; if the "+1"s aren't in subscripts, then it's only affine-linear, not linear.

Comment: yes you are right, this was not edited correctly +1s are not in the subsripts,as you stated.

Comment: I just fixed the subscripts.

Answer (score 0):

$T$ is not a linear transformation.  (Note that $T(0) \neq 0$.)  Therefore, it doesn't make sense to refer to the standard matrix of $T$.

However, let $S(V) = \begin{bmatrix} V_z \\ V_y \\ V_x \end{bmatrix}$.  $S$ is a linear transformation, and the matrix of $S$ with respect to the standard basis $\beta$ of $\mathbb R^3$ is
\begin{equation}
[S]_\beta = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Note that 
\begin{align}
T(V) &= S(V) + \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} V_x \\ V_y \\ V_z \end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

Comment: ok I got it.Thank you!

Comment: Great!  You have the option of accepting answers if you feel the question has been answered.